# What is the best approach to sort the data in Mapper while processing large data set using Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to find top 10 movies from a huge data set using  Hadoop. I am using Map Reduce approach. I have used a local collection i.e TreeMap to sort the data , but this approach is not recommended.May i know the correct approach to sort the data while processing a huge amount inside Mapper ? I am giving the my Mapper and Reducer code

Mapper code

```
public class HighestViewedMoviesMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private TreeMap<Integer, Text> highestView = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();

    @Override
    public void map( Object key, Text values, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String data = values.toString();
        String[] field = data.split( "::", -1 );
        if ( null != field && field.length == 2 ) {
            int views = Integer.parseInt( field[1] );
            highestView.put( views, new Text( field[0] + "::" + field[1] ) );
            if ( highestView.size() > 10 ) {
                highestView.remove( highestView.firstKey() );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup( Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for ( Map.Entry<Integer, Text> entry : highestView.entrySet() ) {
            context.write( NullWritable.get(), entry.getValue() );
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer Code

```
public class HighestViewMoviesReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private TreeMap<Integer, Text> highestView = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();

    public void reduce( NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context )
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for ( Text value : values ) {
            String data = value.toString();
            String[] field = data.split( "::", -1 );
            if ( field.length == 2 ) {
                highestView.put( Integer.parseInt( field[1] ), new Text( value ) );
                if ( highestView.size() > 10 ) {
                    highestView.remove( highestView.firstKey() );
                }
            }
        }
        for ( Text t : highestView.descendingMap().values() ) {
            context.write( NullWritable.get(), t );
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the best approach to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: TreeMap won't work unless for force a single reducer. It's not clear why you need MapReduce instead of Spark, Hive, or Pig

Comment: I need to use mapreduce here , is there any alternative of Tree Map ?

Comment: Mapreduce is distributed process by definition. Therefore, there is only ever one TreeMap per hadoop data split, which is not globally available to map every entry in your data. To sort within mapreduce, you typically need to force data into one reducer

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that ,a small code snippet if possible

Comment: Well, I assume that's what you tried to do with NullWritable class... Have you tried printing out the values in the reducer and look at the job logs? Have you tried unit testing the TreeMap code otherwise for 20 random values, for example? My point is that it's not clear where you think the code is failing. For example, I typically write to the context in the map method, not cleanup

Comment: @cricket_007 its not failing but since TreeMap is a local storage so it is discouraged .

Comment: Well, you need some in-memory, sortable data structure that's able to hold a capacity. It's only discouraged if not used correctly, but this seems fine